# Backprop through un-differentiable function f(x)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

Let's say I have a vector of gradients (ie. `dL / dy`). These gradients are the result of taking the derivative of the Loss function with respect to the output of a function - call it y.

My original function is `y = f(x) = fancy-sort(x)` where x is an input vector of integers and `fancy-sort` is some kind of algorithm to sort the input vector.

How am I supposed to pass the gradient along in this case to find `dL/dx`, for backprop? The function `f(x)` is un-differentiable... no? Do I manually compute the Jacobian ie. for a change in each x, find the change in each of the `y`'s? That way, I could then use this formula `dL / dx = (dL / dy) * (dy / dx)` -->  where `dL / dy` was given and the Jacobian `dy / dx` was manually computed across all combinations of x and y?

It then boils into a matrix multiplication for the last step to calculate `dL / dx`. Is this correct?

Comment: "The function f(x) is un-differentiable... no?" If I got the idea, you have to have L differentiable with respect to x, not f(x).

Comment: "for a change in each x, find the change in each of the y's" - but for sorting, small changes in x values will not result in any change in the sorting order unless you have duplicate values in the vector x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a comment, but unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to comment. Disclaimer, I am the author of some references.

If you have a function that is non-differentiable, let's say in a machine learning pipeline, we need to think about if our function differentiable at least somewhere and whether the derivative is meaningful.
In the case of a sorting function, it is differentiable almost everywhere, i.e., at most places it is differentiable but not everywhere. In this case, depending on the application, the derivative may not be meaningful.

> Do I manually compute the Jacobian ie. for a change in each x, find the change in each of the y's?

Yes, you could do that, which results in a locally differentiable function.

> That way, I could then use this formula dL / dx = (dL / dy) * (dy / dx) --> where dL / dy was given and the Jacobian dy / dx was manually computed across all combinations of x and y?

> It then boils into a matrix multiplication for the last step to calculate dL / dx. Is this correct?

Yes and yes.

To obtain more meaningful gradients for sorting and ranking through a relaxation of the sorting function, the following recent line of work has covered differentiable sorting:

- https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.09630
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.04019
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.08871
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11885
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08850

To obtain more meaningful gradients for general algorithms, the following works might be interesting for you:

- https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.05651
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.08676